# What is better to check is product already imported in MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, import, duplicates, sql-insert

What is better to check is product already imported in MySQL table:

1) by every single query for each product ID

```
foreach ($products_to_import_from_xml as $product) {
    $is_exist = $modx->query("SELECT id FROM modx_ms2_products WHERE crm_id={$product['id']} LIMIT 1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
    if ($is_exist) continue;
    actually_import_new_product_because_it_not_exist_yet($product);
}
```

or

2) use "... WHERE `id` IN(array, of, all, importing, IDs)"?

```
$product_ids_to_import = [];
foreach ($products_to_import_from_xml as $product) {
    $product_ids_to_import[] = $product['id'];
}

$existing_products = $modx->query('SELECT crm_id FROM modx_ms2_products WHERE crm_id IN ('.implode(',', $product_ids_to_import).')')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

foreach ($products_to_import_from_xml as $product) {
    $is_exist = in_array($product['id'], $existing_products);
    if ($is_exist) continue;
    actually_import_new_product_because_it_not_exist_yet($product);
}
```

Comment: How are you importing and at what point do you want to check?

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example of your use case. As it is, you question lacks context and precision, and is not likely to receive a useful answer.

Comment: I importing products into internet shop from XML file (exported from stock inventory program) and want to check each exported product if it already exist in internet shop products table. If I choose 1st way, I can check in `foreach` for each product is it already exist and not to insert it and check this way each next product. Or I can make array list of all exported products (which I want to import), pass them in one single MySQL query and by this way get all products which already imported, and when I loop importing products in `foreach`, check if each product exist in query result list

Comment: @Fullstack: please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62231631/edit) to put the information in there rather than in the comments.

Comment: ' I can check in foreach' - mysql does not have foreach so what other tech is involved?

Comment: Edited my question with code examples (+ added tag PHP)

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would recommend the [`insert ... on duplicate key` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) in MySQL.

For this to work, you need a unique (or primary key) constraint on the products table. Create it if it's not already there:

```
create unique index idx_product_id on products(product_id);
```

Then in the foreach loop of your application code, you can do:

```
insert into products(product_id, ...)  -- enumerate all target columns here
values(:product_id, ...)               -- enumerate all input parameters here
on duplicate key update set product_id = values(product_id);
```

When MySQL encounters a `product_id` that already exists, it skips the `insert` and goes to the `on duplicate key` clause, where a dummy update is performed (the value is not actually re-written, since it is the same as what's already in the table).

Note that, if you have lots of data to import, there are alternatives to consider rather than looping on application side and executing a separate `insert` per row. For high performance inserts, [MySQL recommends the `load data infile` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html), which, as per the documnetation, runs 20 times faster as individual inserts. This would require translating your XML data to CSV format, but it could be worth the effort.

Comment: I wanted to answer this question, but this answer is way better than mine. Learned something new. Thnx!

Comment: I can't use bare `INSERT`-query and I need make some operations in PHP, not MySQL. I also was think about `INSERT - ON DUPLICATE - UPDATE` type of query, but I can't use queries. I work with system (CMS), so it need to do my work via "processors" to run all plugins and make inserts not only to that table. I need to get info about import status in my PHP loop, so that not a way that suits me